# Entityframework count rows when using lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I am trying to count the amount of rows for a specific Account. I configure entityframework to use lazy loading.

I load the account like this:

```
 Account? account = FindSingleOrDefault(x => x.IdCompanyOrUser == id & x.AccountType == accountType);
```

and later on if necessary I try to get the count of the virtual property loginattempts. I do this by executing this:

```
account.LoginAttempts.Count();
```

I read everywhere that this should generate a select count(*) but instead my entityframework is generating the following query:

```
Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int64), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT l."Id", l."AccountIdCompanyOrUser", l."AccountType", l."FailReason", l."Ip", l."Success", l."Time"
FROM "LoginAttempt" AS l
WHERE (l."AccountIdCompanyOrUser" = @__p_0) AND (l."AccountType" = @__p_1) <s:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command>
```

The count result is correct but with this query, it will be loading all the entities first. This could have a serious performance impact when my application is filled with millions of records. For this reason, I really need it to use the select count.

my configuration of entity framework is the following:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasKey(table => new
    {
        table.IdCompanyOrUser,
        table.AccountType
    });
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .Navigation(e => e.LoginAttempts);
```

the login attempt is a virtual list of the model `LoginAttempt` which also has its own table in the database.

I also tried this other options and it didn't work:

```
account.LoginAttempts.Count();
account.LoginAttempts.AsQueryable().Count();
account.LoginAttempts.AsQueryable().ToList().Count();
```

Additional information:

`Version Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2`

`Version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.5`

`.Net 6`

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'where' and 'select' combined

```
db.Table
.Where(x => x.IdCompanyOrUser == id & x.AccountType == accountType)
.Select(x => x.LoginAttemps.Count()).FirstOrDefault()
```

Edit:
As gert arnolt pointed out below, using `Include` is unnecessary so I removed it.

> Include is needed ONLY for loading related entities. It has zero
> influence on filters. LINQ translator will still create SQL because it
> uses just metadata information - what is needed for filter

Comment: You have to remove the `Include`. It does nothing, so it's only distracting and even makes it look like all `LoginAttemps` are still loaded.

Comment: if i remove it,  wouldn't `x.LoginAttemps` be null?

Comment: @OkanKaradag, `Include` is needed ONLY for loading related entities. It has zero influence on filters. LINQ translator will still create SQL because it uses just metadata information - what is needed for filter.

Comment: Ty. I understand. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my architecture I have no access to the dbcontext where the loginattempts are being count. The reason for this is for other programmers not to skip business logic.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior. When you access Lazy Loading navigation property - EF loads property, in your case whole collection. Then Count is performed on loaded collection.

To get just count of items you have to run query again:

```cs
var attemptsCount = _context.Accounts
   .Where(a => a.Id == account.Id)
   .Select(a => a.LoginAttempts.Count())
   .First();
```

Or faster variant

```cs
var attemptsCount = _context.LoginAttempts
   .Where(a => a.AccountId == account.Id)
   .Count();
```

Comment: you cannot write `where` conditional (as AccountType) for `Account` in option 2.

Comment: @OkanKaradag, OP already loaded `account`, we can reuse PK in this case.

Comment: I have no access to the dbcontext where the count is being called. Also to avoid other programmers from skipping business login, loginattempts is not accesable as DBset but only as owned type of an account.

Comment: So, then you have to improve your abstraction :)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for your feedback. I will have it into consideration. However, I still find it interesting. The idea of lazy loading is to load the data only at the moment you need it. If the account has been already retrieved it would be ideal to be able to retrieve only the count of the login attempts without having to get the account again from the context. Maybe it is not possible. But I think it's something that would be quite useful.

Comment: I'm personally think that Lazy loading is a bad idea ;) N+1 query problem will appear almost instantly. Also I'm not a fan of such abstractions. `DbSet` is already repository and `DbContext` is already UoW.